Using webpack + firebase, fs.js is creating paths to a directory rather than a file
I am trying to get a very basic project running using both webpack and firebase. However, I am running into issues when using firebase serve to locally host my site. The site should simply load firebase, and then in the entry file console.log() it. However, I am getting the following error:
SystemError [ERR_FS_EISDIR]: Path is a directory: read returned ERR_FS_EISDIR (is a directory) C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\webdev\learning-firebase\firebaseHosting\public\
    at new ReadStream (node:internal/fs/streams:185:5)
    at Object.createReadStream (node:fs:3087:10)
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\fnm\node-versions\v23.1.0\installation\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\superstatic\lib\providers\fs.js:55:27
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at fetchEtag (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\fnm\node-versions\v23.1.0\installation\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\superstatic\lib\providers\fs.js:49:16)
    at Responder.provider (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\fnm\node-versions\v23.1.0\installation\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\superstatic\lib\providers\fs.js:91:29)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)

Here is my firebase.json file:
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "firebaseHosting/public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}

my webpack.config.js:
const path = require('path');

const dist = path.join(__dirname, './firebaseHosting/public');

module.exports = {
  // The entry point file described above
  entry: './src/index.js',
  // The location of the build folder described above
  output: {
    path: dist,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  // Optional and for development only. This provides the ability to
  // map the built code back to the original source format when debugging.
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',

  devServer: {
    headers: {
      'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin',
      // Add any other headers here
    },
    static: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), // Serve files from dist folder
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
  }
};

and my package.json with dependencies collapsed:
{
  "name": "learning-firebase",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode=development",
    "start": "webpack serve --mode=development"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.96.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}

I have already had to change something in fs.js, as I believe the time was being returned in the wrong format. I changed
return {
    modified: stat.mtime.getTime(),
    size: stat.size,
    etag: await fetchEtag(stat.pathname, stat),
    stream: fs.createReadStream(stat.pathname),
};

to
return {
    modified: stat.mtimeMs,
    size: stat.size,
    etag: await fetchEtag(stat.pathname, stat),
    stream: fs.createReadStream(stat.pathname),
};

so this may be affecting it? I am pretty new to web development so I apologize if this is an overly basic question, but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
